# Kafka MirrorMaker 2.0 Replication Flow Issue: Always writes to the same cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

As part of the DR plan, I'm implementing Kafka MirrorMaker 2.0 to replicate the data between 2 clusters.

At this point I'm only trying to do a simple active/passive design.

This is my mm2.properties file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under A or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# see org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig for more details

# Sample MirrorMaker 2.0 top-level configuration file
# Run with ./bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh connect-mirror-maker.properties 

# specify any number of cluster aliases
clusters = west, central

# connection information for each cluster
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs for each cluster
# for e.g. "A_host1:9092, A_host2:9092, A_host3:9092"
west.bootstrap.servers = kafka-west.com:30002
central.bootstrap.servers = kafka-central.com:30002

# enable and configure individual replication flows
west->central.enabled = true
central->west.enabled = false

# Setting replication factor of newly created remote topics
replication.factor=3

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for mm2 internal topics "heartbeats", "B.checkpoints.internal" and
# "mm2-offset-syncs.B.internal"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=3
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=3
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=3

# The replication factor for connect internal topics "mm2-configs.B.internal", "mm2-offsets.B.internal" and
# "mm2-status.B.internal"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.replication.factor=3

# customize as needed
# replication.policy.separator = _
# sync.topic.acls.enabled = false
# emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds = 5
```

The problem is here (I think?):

```
west->central.enabled = true
central->west.enabled = false
```

No matter how I configure the flow, I only see data being written on the `west` cluster. Even with both flows to true, the `west` cluster then gets `west.topic` and `central.topic`. Meanwhile, the `central` cluster never gets any replication.

I have also run this Mirror-Maker config in both clusters, it always gets written to `west` cluster for some reason.

I do not understand why this happens, thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT:
I'm losing my mind a bit. I switched both URLs to be `central` like this:

```
west.bootstrap.servers = kafka-central.com:30002
central.bootstrap.servers = kafka-central.com:30002
```

and it STILL writes to the `west` cluster... how is this possible, when he doesn't even know where the `west` cluster is? I even checked the DNSs and they are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was something in my brokers on the `central` cluster that were pointing to the Loadbalancer on the `west` cluster.

After fixing the brokers the replication flow was correct again